# displaying flag image in listview from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database with a "flagname" field. What I want to do is display a listview with the relevant flag in the image view that corresponds with the database field, along side a text field. The text field from the database is being displayed ok, but I'm having trouble displaying the relevant flag beside it. Can someone please let me know where I'm going wrong.  My code is listed below:

public class favourites extends Activity{

```
Cursor cursor;
ListView lv;
ImageView iv;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listmain);  
    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgFlag);


    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();

    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    //Get cursor for list items
    cursor = db.getAllRadioStations();

    //assign fields to columns
    String[] columns = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_STATION_NAME.toString()};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.txtFlag};

    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.flagchoice, cursor, columns, to);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);



}
```

Comment: From what I see, you are loading a single column "DBAdapter.KEY_STATION_NAME" to a single TextView "R.id.txtFlag". Can you clarify where do you store your flags and how do you load them? Or is this what you need to do?

Comment: I'm storing my flags in the res\drawable folder. Basically what I want to do is match the image to the text flag field in the database, meaning that if the text said "Brazil" then the image view in the listview, should be the Brazilian flag, or if the text said "spain", the image beside the text box in the listview should be the Spanish flag. Hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is override the Adapter.setViewBinder(). Try this:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.flagchoice, cursor, columns, to);

adapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {

public boolean setViewValue(View aView, Cursor aCursor, int aColumnIndex) {

String country=aCursor.getString(aColumnIndex);

int id = getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackagename:drawable/" + country , null, null);

iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgFlag);

iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(id));

TextView tv=(TextView) aView;
tv.setText(aCursor.getString(aColumnIndex));
return true;

}
});
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I've tried it and the text part works but for some reason the when I try and reference the image as per your code, I get an "exception - resources not found" error. Here's the code: int id = getResources().getIdentifier("com.PecApps:drawable-hdpi/france_flag", null, null);
    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgFlag);
    iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(id));   I used the french flag in the directory just to test that the image view was displaying correct and it culminated in an error.

Comment: remove "-hdpi" (just drawable/)

Comment: I've tried that and I still get a resource not found error :-(

Comment: Try cleaning the project (from Eclipse, Project -> Clean). Also, please print the value of country and the exact name of the resource file (note that special charcters and upper case are not allowed for resource name)